# Does jwt use the current time as an input, so as to give different token each time asked

Tags: javascript, jwt

```
  const createToken = async (user, secret, expiresIn) => {
    const { id, email, username } = user;
    return await jwt.sign({ id, email, username }, secret, {
      expiresIn
    });
  };
```

jwt for the same input, results different token.

```
const user = {
    id: '1',
    email: 'henok@gmail.com',
    username: 'henoktes72'
}

createToken(user, secret, '30m')
```

So I assume that jwt uses current time as an input. But that raises another question, How does a server verifies the token? If current time is in the token, the server will never verify a token as valid, because of different time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several doubts about how JWT works in general, so I will offer a brief introduction to how they work.  Your JWT internally contains several pieces of information known as *claims*.  They would typically include something like the following:

- username
- expiryTime
- level

To focus on your specific question, the `expiryTime` (standard name `exp`) stores a timestamp for when the JWT expires.  The first thing the server will do to verify the incoming JWT will be open it and check that the expiry time has not passed.  If it *has* passed, then the server will immediately reject the token.  So, the expiry time is used as a gatekeeper to keep out stale tokens from your application.

Beyond this, there would usually be another verification step, where the server would have to hit something like a cache or maybe a database to check that the JWT is actually still valid.  For this check, the `username` or some other unique identifier corresponding to the user, would be used as key for lookup.

I also included a claim which I called the `level`.  Assuming your application might have different levels of authentication, the level might store state corresponding to that.

Comment: Thank you, but I read that the server verifies the token on the fly, instead of comparing with stored token.

Comment: _Stored_ token?  Where did I mention anything about storing the token?

Comment: Beyond this, there would usually be another verification step, where the server would have to hit something like a `cache or maybe a database` to check that the JWT is actually still valid. For this check, the username or some other unique identifier corresponding to the user, would be used as key for lookup.

Comment: Yes, but I never said store the token.  Only a very small entry in a cache or database would be made.  And yes, you need to do this, in general, because JWT isn't completely stateless.  Not unless you never need to restrict a token, which probably is not your case.

Comment: Yes, So there server can't verify the token on the fly.

Comment: OK...the server _can_ evaluate the token on the fly, _but_ there is a caveat.  Let's say that one of your users logs out.  Now, you have a problem.  It is a problem because there is a valid JWT out there, which your user indicated that he wanted to invalidate.  So, one way of dealing with this is to add that user's JWT to a blacklist (cache, database, etc.).  Then, it someone else tries to use that JWT, your server can check the cache and reject.  But...this now means that you have to maintain some small state.

Comment: In theory, JWT can be made to be almost completely stateless, but it requires a bit of engineering and design work.  It is a good framework, if you have the interest to try to use it.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye If I left out any major points you needed covered, drop a comment and maybe I can add something to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't usees the `current time + expiresIn` as the expiration time.
if you decode a jwt token you will see there are two fields `iat` & `exp`, where `iat` is the time where the time when the token as created.

```
jwt.sign({ id, email, username }, secret, {
      expiresIn: '30m'
});
```

this code is the equivalent as

```
jwt.sign({ id, email, username, exp: Date.now()+30*60*1000 }, secret);
```

Comment: Thank you @PrithweeDas. You didn't mention how the server verifies the token.